# input-group is not working fine with form-group

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have template loaded by angularJS, which HTML is look like this.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <p class="panel-title">Project Detail - {{Name}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="Descriptiion">Description</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="Description" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group" id="startDate">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="startDate" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.Name.$invalid" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

output looks like below attached image[image]

There is gap between control and ad-on Icon.  Also there lot of blank space on right side of the controls, though I am using col-sm-10 class.

Answer (score 0):

Try following css from cdn it is working fine

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I am using nuget package version 3.3.6 only in Visual Studio.  This is a MVC application and template is a partial view.